# Disable plugin ckeditor per content type

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using the [ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module.
I have 2 content types.
Both content types use the same ckeditor profile on their body field.

Is it possible, without creating another profile, to disable a certain plugin (e.g. image plugin) on that ckeditor profile for only one content type?

Answer (score 2):

You need create different "body field" in one of your content type.
I.e. For first content type use the same "body field" and use first ckeditor profile.
For next content type create a new "body field" - like a "content_type_name_body" and use last ckeditor profile.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use another profile and creating another body field is not an option. I should have stated that more clearly in my question. The profiles I have are similar except for one enabled plugin. I'm looking more for an "extends" functionality where plugins that both field need are shared and where I can add an exception for just one plugin that one field needs.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a same issue and did it using [Better Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats) module.

1. I created a new Input Format (for example "my input format")
2. Disabled WYSIWYG in that format
3. In the Content type settings, under "Input format settings", select that new profile as default

Answer (score 0):

In a custom module, have some code similar to this:

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'profile_node_form') { //change profile to be your content type
      $form['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#wysiwyg'] = FALSE; 
  }    
}
```

body is the field name, you might need to change it if you're using a different / more fields.

It is probably best to name your module with something in the alphabet later than 'ckeditor' or use the moduleweights module to ensure your hook runs after ckeditor... I say probably because I haven't tested to see if this is an issue or not.